# SystemVerilog - clk not toggling in verification

Tags: system-verilog, testbench

I'm testing an AES encryption machine that's written in Verilog. I know that the DUT is perfect because I created a Verilog testbench.

When I simulate in VCS, the clk stays at 0 the whole time and the rest of the input/outputs are X. In the log file, none of the transactions are printed so I think that it's a clock problem.

I'm getting a warning for ANSI redeclaration for the clk, so I commented out the clk wire in the interface but the result is the same.

Am I missing a connection? Or am I not connecting the DUT correctly? Do you always have to use clocking blocks and modports with a modular testbench in SystemVerilog?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

//Top Level
module top();

  //clk generator
  reg clk = 0;
  always #5 clk = ~clk;
   
  
  //DUT Instantiation
  aes_intf intf(clk);
  
  aes_128 DUT(
    clk,
    intf.key,
    intf.state,
    intf.out
  );
  
  testcase test(intf);
  
endmodule


//Connections to DUT
interface aes_intf(input clk);
  //wire clk;
  wire [127:0] state, key;
  wire [127:0] out;
endinterface

//Instances of driver, etc
class environment;
  driver drvr;
  virtual aes_intf intf;
  
  function new(virtual aes_intf intf);
    this.intf = intf;
    drvr = new(intf);
  endfunction
  
endclass
```

```
//Stimulus Generator for 128-bit AES Encryption DUT
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

//Base Transaction
class transaction;
    rand bit [127:0] state;
    rand bit [127:0] key;
                          
    function void print(string tag="");   //print for log file
      $display("state=0x%h  key=0x%h", state, key);
    endfunction
  
endclass

//Generates stimulus and drives to DUT
class driver; 
  rand transaction trans; //transaction object
  int iterations;
  virtual aes_intf intf; //interface instance
  
  //Constructor
  function new(virtual aes_intf intf);
    this.intf = intf;
  endfunction
  
  task drive(input integer interations);
    repeat(iterations) begin    //send x transactions
        trans = new();
      @(posedge intf.clk);
      if(!trans.randomize())$fatal("Transaction failed");
        intf.key = trans.key;
        intf.state = trans.state;
    end
  endtask

endclass
```

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

program testcase(aes_intf intf);
  
  environment env = new(intf);
  
  initial begin
    env.drvr.drive(10);
  end
  
endprogram
```

Comment: @toolic here's the collaborate link to the EDA Playground that I've been using https://www.edaplayground.com/x/s5q_#&togetherjs=8BupNkfxgj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in the `driver` class (`interations`).  Change:

```
  task drive(input integer interations);
```

to:

```
  task drive(input integer iterations);
```

You did not get a compile error because you declared `iterations` as a class-level variable.

The problem with your simulation was that no time elapsed in the `drive` task.  When you passed the value `10` to `drive`, the `interations` variable was assigned to 10.  However, the `iterations` variable remained 0 because you declared it as `int`, and you did not assign it a value.  Therefore, the `repeat` loop never executed, and the simulation ended at time 0.